# WPF datagrid cannot add a row after binding to collection with data

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a wpf applicatiion with multiple datagrids, all bound to seperate ObservableCollections  of custom objects. When the collections are empty, i see a blank row and I can add data.

However, when I add objects to the collections programmatically (read from XML), ONE of the datagrids does not show a blank row and does not allow me to add data, while the others do.

I have checked the cunstructors of all objects to be public, and I refresh all datagrids programmatically after I add objects the collections. All datagrid have the property CanUserAddRows set to true.

Has anybody have an idea what could be the reason? I could not find any answer through a search here.

JW