# Datagrid: User cannot edit or select a row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, edit

I'm using a Datagrid in WPF to display rows of users returned from a LINQ-SQL expression in a List:

```
private void admin_tab_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dbMethods.CheckDatabaseConnection())
    {
        using (PubsDataContext db = new PubsDataContext())
        {
            var Allusers = new List<Application_User>(from users in db.Application_Users
                                                      select users);
            users_DataGrid.DataContext = Allusers;
        }
    }
}
```

The users load just fine, row by row with all the information intact.  However, when the rows are left clicked the row does not become selected and there appears to be no event being passed.  I added in a MouseDown event and can only capture right-clicks, but never a left click.

The XAML for the Datagrid is:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="6,6,6,215" Name="users_DataGrid" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="286" Width="246"
                              MouseLeftButtonDown="users_DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDown="users_DataGrid_MouseDown"/>
```

This is identical code I have for a separate datagrid on a different window, both XAML and C#.  Here is that sample for comparison:

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="1,136,1,207" Name="studentLearningExperiences_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="studentLearningExperiences_ContextMenu">
            <!--HACK BUG - currently does not work with the button click <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="learningExperienceSave_BTN_Click" /> -->
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_MenuItem_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
public void LoadStudentLearningExperiences()
{
    if (dbMethods.CheckDatabaseConnection())
    {
        using (PubsDataContext db = new PubsDataContext())
        {
            var completionList = new List<Learning_Experience>(from s in db.Learning_Experiences
                                                               where s.Student_ID == student.Student_ID
                                                               select s);
            studentLearningExperiences_DataGrid.DataContext = completionList;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone find if I have a error, missed something, or advise from their experience?  I have referenced this link [Cannot edit cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385950/cannot-edit-cells-of-my-datagrid-wpf-framework-4-5) and am wondering if my SQL Server Tables are creating TextBlocks rather than TexBoxes but the tables in SQL Server also appear identical.

Comment: similar question found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955601/wpf-datagrid-cannot-add-a-row-after-binding-to-collection-with-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a break for the weekend, and came back at the datagrid problem this morning.  My application is based around multiple tabs the user can cycle between, so I tried hosting the datagrid on a separate tab and filling the datacontext from the MainWIndow constructor.  This worked, so then I tried loading the original datagrid from the constructor and it worked too.

Turns out the problem was with the "Got Focus" attribute of the tab calling the LINQ that filled the datagrid.  Here is the code before:

```
<TabItem Header="Admin" Name="admin_tab" GotFocus="admin_tab_GotFocus" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid Name="grdAminTab" Margin="0,0,710,-1">        
                    <Button Content="Save" Height="23" Name="saveNewUser_BTN" Width="75" Click="saveUser_BTN_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Button Content="Delete" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,298,0,0" Name="deleteUser_BTN" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="deleteUser_BTN_Click" />
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="6,6,6,215" Name="users_DataGrid" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="286" Width="246" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

And after:

```
<TabItem Header="Faculty" IsEnabled="False" Name="faculty_tab" />
        <TabItem Header="Admin" Name="admin_tab" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid Name="grdAminTab" Margin="0,0,710,-1">        
                    <Button Content="Save" Height="23" Name="saveNewUser_BTN" Width="75" Click="saveUser_BTN_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Button Content="Delete" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,298,0,0" Name="deleteUser_BTN" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="deleteUser_BTN_Click" />
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="6,6,6,215" Name="users_DataGrid" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="286" Width="246" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

Not sure if there is a reason to loading the datagrid before the user opens that tab is a bad practice, but for now it has solved my problem!  Any insights into why this event handler was not working would be greatly appreciated.  I have run into similar problems with the EventArgs not being correct for a mouse event, maybe this is similar?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue and found that each time a click is performed on a control that is within a tab that the "SelectionChanged" event fires for that tab. I put in a check in the code behind for the "SelectionChanged" handler to make sure the code only executes once per tab entry.